# Calling Fortran shared library in Python with ctypes

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I'm trying to use a Fortran module in Python. I have several arrays in Python -- both numeric and string. I defined the arrays in Fortran and Python, but I think that I used the wrong type for the numeric arrays. I get an error that converting the first argument (a numeric array) failed. What types should I use?

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_try.py", line 66, in <module>
    writelittler.write_obs(p,z,t,td,spd,wdir,slp,ter,xlat,xlon,date_char,num_met,num_lev,kx,dd_strvar,station_strvar,synop,string4, bogus, iseq_num, iunit)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

**Fortran:**

```fortran
subroutine write_obs(p, z, t, td, spd, wdir, xlon, kx, slp, ter, xlat,  date_char, dd, station, num_met, num_lev, synop, string4, bogus, iseq_num, iunit) bind(C, name='write_obs')
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
integer(c_int) k, kx, num_met, num_lev, iseq_num, iunit, ierr
real(kind=c_float) p(kx), slp(kx), z(kx), t(kx), td(kx)
real(kind=c_float) spd(kx), ter(kx), xlat(kx), xlon(kx), wdir(kx)
character(len=1,kind=c_char) date_char
character(len=1,kind=c_char) synop, string4
character(len=1,kind=c_char), intent(in) :: dd(kx)
character(len=1,kind=c_char), intent(in) :: station(kx)
logical(c_bool) bogus
character(len=84,kind=c_char) rpt_format
character(len=22,kind=c_char) meas_format
character(len=14,kind=c_char) end_format

rpt_format = ' ( 2f20.5 , 2a40 , '&
&' 2a40 , 1f20.5 , 5i10 , 3L10 , '&
&' 2i10 , a20 , 13( f13.5 , i7 ) )'

meas_format = ' ( 10( f13.5 , i7 ) ) '
end_format = ' ( 3 ( i7 ) )'

do 100 k=1 , kx

write ( UNIT = iunit , iostat = ierr , FMT = rpt_format ) &
& xlat(k), xlon(k), dd(k), station(k), &
& synop , string4, ter(k), num_met, 0, 0, iseq_num, 0, &
& .true., bogus, .false., &
& -888888, -888888, date_char, slp(k), 0, &
& -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0, &
& -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0, &
& -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0, &
& -888888., 0

write ( UNIT = iunit , iostat = ierr , FMT = meas_format ) &
& p(k), 0, z(k), 0, t(k), 0, td(k), 0, &
& spd(k), 0, wdir(k), 0, &
& -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0


write ( UNIT = iunit , iostat = ierr, FMT = meas_format ) &
& -777777., 0, -777777., 0, float(num_lev), 0, &
& -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0, &
& -888888., 0, -888888., 0, -888888., 0, &
& -888888., 0

write ( UNIT = iunit, iostat = ierr, FMT = end_format ) &
& num_lev, 0, 0

if (ierr .NE. 0 ) then
    print '(A,I5,A)','Troubles writing a sounding.Error #', ierr
    stop 'writing_error'
endif
100 continue
return
end subroutine write_obs
```

**Python:**

```python
import numpy as np
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_int, c_char
writelittler=ctypes.CDLL("/writelittler.so")
p = np.asarray([ 982.6, 999.7 ], dtype="float64")
p_strvar=ctypes.c_void_p(p.ctypes.data)

# [other numerical arrays omitted]

bogus = 0
kx=2
iseq_num = 0
iunit=2
date_char = '      20160128060000'
dt=np.dtype('a40')
dd = np.asarray([ '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111', '6666666666666666666666666666666666666666', '9999999999999999999999999999999999999999'  ], dtype=dt)
station = np.asarray([ 'V111111111111111111111111111111111111111','M111111111111111111111111111111111111111' ], dtype=dt)

dd_strvar=ctypes.c_void_p(dd.ctypes.data)
station_strvar=ctypes.c_void_p(station.ctypes.data)
num_met=6
num_lev=1
synop='FM-12 SYNOP                             '
string4='                                        '

writelittler.write_obs(p,z,t,td,spd,wdir,slp,ter,xlat, xlon,date_char,num_met,num_lev,kx,dd_strvar, station_strvar,synop,string4, bogus, iseq_num, iunit)
```

Comment: When passing a numpy array, use its `ctypes` attribute, e.g. `x.ctypes` and not `c_void_p(x.ctypes.data)`. For the first argument you're mistakenly passing the numpy array `p` instead of `p.ctypes`. Make sure the numeric types match up (e.g. `c_float` <=> `float32`, `c_double` <=> `float64`).

Comment: For passing by value, doesn't Fortran's C binding require you to explicitly declare a parameter as by `value`? Otherwise arguments are passed by reference. For example, `integer(c_int), intent(in), value :: k, kx`.

Comment: @eryksun Indeed. But I would propose to declare the argtypes explicitly as `POINTER(c_float)`, etc.

Comment: @Palina Where do you specify `z`, `t`, and all the other variables in your Python code? You are accessing them in Fortran!

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify the argument types of the Fortran subroutine in Python. Furthermore, you do not declare/initialize the variables you pass to Fortran either. Therefore, Python does not know what to do with it. That is what it is telling you in the error message.

As Fortran uses call by reference by default, the `argtypes` are:

```
writelittler.write_obs.argtypes = [ POINTER(c_float), # p
                                    POINTER(c_float), # z
                                    POINTER(c_float), # t
                                    POINTER(c_float), # td
                                    POINTER(c_float), # spd
                                    POINTER(c_float), # wdir
                                    POINTER(c_int),   # kx
                                    POINTER(c_float), # slp
                                    POINTER(c_float), # ter
                                    POINTER(c_float), # xlat
                                    POINTER(c_char),  # date_char
                                    POINTER(c_char),  # dd
                                    POINTER(c_char),  # station
                                    POINTER(c_int),   # num_met
                                    POINTER(c_int),   # num_lev
                                    POINTER(c_char),  # synop
                                    POINTER(c_int),   # string4
                                    POINTER(c_bool),  # bogus
                                    POINTER(c_bool),  # string4
                                    POINTER(c_int),   # iseq_num
                                    POINTER(c_int)    # iunit
                                  ]
```

[This can probably be simplified...]

Additionally, Fortran subroutines do not have a return value:

```
writelittler.write_obs.restype = None
```

Furthermore, you need to adjust the function call itself (in Python):

```
writelittler.write_obs( p.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float)), # Numpy data type
                        ctypes.byref(z), # ctypes data type
                        ctypes.byref(t),
                        ctypes.byref(td),
                        ctypes.byref(spd),
                        ctypes.byref(wdir),
                        ctypes.byref(slp),
                        ctypes.byref(ter),
                        ctypes.byref(xlat), 
                        ctypes.byref(xlon),
                        ctypes.byref(date_char),
                        ctypes.byref(num_met),
                        ctypes.byref(num_lev),
                        ctypes.byref(kx),
                        ctypes.byref(dd_strvar), 
                        ctypes.byref(station_strvar),
                        ctypes.byref(synop),
                        ctypes.byref(string4), 
                        ctypes.byref(bogus), 
                        ctypes.byref(iseq_num), 
                        ctypes.byref(iunit) )
```

[This is not validated...]

Now that Python knows what to expect, you still need to declare the missing variables. As your code is know, it will result in the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 51, in <module>
>     writelittler.write_obs(p,z,t,td,spd,wdir,slp,ter,xlat, 
> xlon,date_char,num_met,num_lev,kx,dd_strvar,
> station_strvar,synop,string4, bogus, iseq_num, iunit)
> NameError: name 'z' is not defined
> ```

Comment: If I were going to declare `argtypes` then I'd use a numpy pointer type such as `npf8arr_t = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype='float64')`. This way the OP can pass a numpy array `x` directly instead of passing `x.ctypes`.

Comment: Also, if the OP controls the Fortran API, the integer parameters should be changed to pass by `value`. Otherwise this will be a tedious interface such as `num_met = ctypes.c_int(6)`; `write_obs(..., ctypes.byref(num_met), ...)`. instead of simply `num_met = 6;` `write_obs(..., num_met, ...)`.

Comment: @eryksun Actually, I would prefer the more tedious way of writing it. Usually, large numpy arrays are passed, and I would try to avoid copying the content. But you are right, I should add the changes to the function call as well.

Comment: Who said anything about copying the array arguments? The `ndpointer` type doesn't copy arguments. Its `from_param` method validates that the numpy array type matches the required constraints in type, dimension, shape, and flags, and then it simply passes the `ctypes` attribute, which defines the `_as_parameter_` property that has the base address of the array as a `c_void_p` instance. No copy is created.

Comment: @eryksun In Fortran, if you specify `value` you switch to call by value.

Comment: I only suggested `value` be used for the simple integer parameters such as `num_met`, not for arrays.

Comment: @Eryksun, ah, I see. That would indeed simplify a few things. But I would still not use it - it is a little more work when writing, but it will still be a little bit more efficient.  Especially for so many arguments ;-) It depends on the use case, I guess.

Comment: Passing an integer by reference requires instantiating a `ctypes.c_int`, which requires converting the Python integer to a C `int` buffer,  and then a `cparam` object is created via `byref` that points at the buffer, and finally the `cparam` value is copied to the stack or register. Passing it by value is similar, but the integer value is converted and stored directly in the `cparam` object and copied to the stack or register instead of copying the address. But as far as usage is concerned, it's a lot simpler to skip the `c_int` and `byref` steps in Python.